# selection of column based on max value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `count` with the attributes

- count1
- count2
- count3
- count4
- count5

I want to select a column having maximum value. How do I do that?

The count represents page hits and I want to select a column having maximum hits and display it.

Comment: why have you named the columns as `count1`, `count2` and so on? Are they denoting some meaning?

Comment: I don not think those are the actual names of the columns....

Comment: kst - once a question is answered, normally a tick is put against the answer to mark it as accepted. This in a sense "closes" off the question

Comment: thanx for the answer ,but instead of getting the count i want to get the column name how can i get that ,ie is it possible to get te column name based on the record in the row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a doubly nested subquery

```
select 
  (select max(count1)
   from (
    select count1 union all
    select count2 union all
    select count3 union all
    select count4 union all
    select count5) X) as MaxCount
from tbl
```

Comment: @Uw Concept: {subquery} UNION ALL {subquery} -> creates a derived table made up of all the records from both subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, involving `PIVOT` or a `Temp Table`, but i think the easiest to understand is using `Case` for this.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN count1 >= count2 AND count2 >= count3 AND count1 >= count4 AND count1 >= count5 THEN count1
        WHEN count2 >= count3 AND count2 >= count4 AND count2 >= count5 THEN count2
        WHEN count3 >= count4 AND count3 >= count5 THEN count3
        WHEN count4 >= count5 THEN count4
        ELSE count5
    END AS highestCount
```

Comment: Note: If any of the counts are NULL, your chain will be broken.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, using COALESCE(countX, 0) around the columns might help

Answer (score 0):

```
   select MAX(max_count) FROM
   (
   select  count1 as max_count from count 
   UNION
   select  count2 as max_count from count 
   UNION
   select  count3 as max_count from count 
   UNION
   select  count4 as max_count from count 
   UNION 
   select  count4 as max_count from count
   )
```

I would not suggest using Select as it takes lot of time to generate the same. Triggers would be better